# How to forward to another subpage

Tags: python, selenium, forwarding

Today I started my first project in Selenium with Python.
I'm going to write a program that will automate buying items on a
website. I'm going to expand functions of this bot in future updates, but right now I need that first thing done.

What the program should do right now:

1. Program has to login to site
2. Program has to forward to subsite - here is problem. I'm getting logged off from site and next step of course doesn't work.
3. Program has to choose size and then click "add to cart."

The program works fine if I don't use forwarding but click on the next parts of the site. This means that if I want to get forwarded from the home page to the product page it doesn't work - I get logged off. When I click, for example, home -> shoes -> name of shoe, everything works fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\damia\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')

stronaLog="https://www.zalando-lounge.pl/#/login"
stronaKup="https://www.zalando-lounge.pl/campaigns/ZZO0TCY/categories/5999626/articles/AD115O085-A12"

#getting to the site
browser.get(stronaLog)

#logging
email = browser.find_element_by_id('form-email').send_keys('myemail')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('form-password').send_keys('mypass' + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)

#save cookies
cookie={'name': 'MojCiasteczek', 'value':'666666'}
browser.add_cookie(cookie)

#forwading to next site and buying product
browser.get(stronaKup)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '41 1/3')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#addToCartButton > div.articleButton___add-to-cart___1Nngf.core___flipper___3yDf4').click()
```

Comment: Some things to check. 1. Does the page actually submit(attempt to log in) after the line with `Keys.ENTER`? 2. Are you forwarding before the login process completes? (IE. do you actually see the page you'd expect after successful login before forwarding?) 3. Does it work if you take out the `browser.add_cookie(cookie)` line? (In case that's messing with the login token you get somehow... longshot troubleshooting there.)

Comment: Also, it's generally considered bad practice to set `implicitly_wait` during a test as it is almost never used correctly or changed back correctly and can lead to some creepy bugs, especially if you have tests running in parallel. But I wouldn't think that is causing your issue here.

Comment: @mrfreester 1. If I delete rest of code, it does. With rest of code some times it redirects me to te procduct page, but sometimes it shows me a logging page.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, what happens if you use the `time` library -> `import time`... and add this line before forwarding to the subpage ->`time.sleep(10)`? Please note, this is NOT a great solution, just seeing if you need to wait for the authentication to complete.

Comment: That time.sleep(2) - 2 is enought helped me

Comment: @mrfreester I edited post. Now it shows working code. Is there something that I should change?

Comment: Yes, I'll give a general example of an explicit wait in an answer. You should be doing that instead of a sleep because sleeps are inherently slow and flakey as test projects grow. Glad we found the issue! Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the authentication process hasn't completed by the time you attempt to navigate to a url that requires the user to be logged in.

As discussed in the comments, to test this theory a `sleep` was added to wait for authentication to complete and that appeared to work.

Rather than using a `sleep`, a more robust approach would be to wait for some element to appear on the landing page. I'll give steps for a general example:

1. here are the `import` statements you'll need:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

1. Identify some element on the landing page after login... Like a welcome text, or anything really that's not also on the login page. For this example let's say the element you identify has an `id="Welcome"`, of course yours will be different.
2. Use this code to wait for that element:

```
WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Welcome")))
```

This code will wait up to 5 seconds for that element to be present, but will return as soon as it finds it. Change the seconds to wait to the maximum possible time you would expect the login to take.

After that you should be able to navigate to your other url as an authenticated user:

```
browser.get(stronaKup)
```